# Powershell equivalent of Perl's $CHILD_ERROR

Tags: windows, powershell, perl, exit, exit-code

I essentially require a functionality in Powershell that executes the given string (it can be a CMD/Powershell command, a perl/python/powershell with arguments or an exe with arguments, etc) captures its exit value.
In perl I would pass the string to 'system()' and use the '$CHILD_ERROR' perlval and shift it to access the exit code.

In powershell I am clueless.

I tried using Invoke-Expression, but even if the expression passed to Invoke-Expression fails, the Invoke-Expression call itself will have succeeded.

Comment: Pro-tip: it is excessively rare to find a valid use-case for `Invoke-Expression`.  Avoid it whenever possible.  What you want is the *call operator* (`&`)

Comment: Using & sets the $? correctly, so I will know whether the command succeeded or failed. BUT, it won't set the $LASTEXITCODE to the command's return value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **$LASTEXITCODE** to get the exit code from an external program or the Boolean **$?** to check if the last operation succeeded or failed. Run **Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables -ShowWindow** from a PowerShell console to see more details.

You may want to check out the **&** (call) command as an alternative to **Invoke-Expression** when running external programs. Run **Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables -ShowWindow** from a PowerShell console for details.

Also remember you may be able to just call the external program without using one of the commands above. See the example below:

```
param($Hostname="127.0.0.1", $Tries=1, $Wait=1000)
$output = ping.exe $Hostname -n $Tries -w $Wait # captures anything written to stdout
$output|? {$_ -match 'Request timed out'}|Write-Warning
$LASTEXITCODE # returns the exit code from ping.exe
```

You can copy it to a test.ps1 file and run it from a PowerShell console window  (.\test.ps1 8.8.8.8 for instance) to see how it works.

Comment: In my scenario I will always get the command as a parameter string, so I will need someone to execute it. Lets say the command is: $command = "mkdir aaa:bbbccc", which is sent as a script parameter. This command will obviously fail! But, after the statement: $output = Invoke-Expression $command, the $LASTEXITCODE is 0 (probably because the invoke-expression successfully fired mkdir, even though mkdir failed) and $? is also $True.

Comment: In this scenario you are running PowerShell's built-in **mkdir** command so **$LASTEXITCODE** is not set but you could use the call (**&**) command and trap the exception to handle the error. On the other hand, if you need to run the **mkdir** command from **cmd.exe** you'll need code like this: `$cmd="cmd.exe"; $params="/c mkdir dir1\dir2"; &$cmd $params; $LASTEXITCODE`. Run it twice, it should succeed (and print 0) the first time and fail (and print 1) the second one as the folder will already exist.This way **$LASTEXITCODE** is populated as we are running an external program.